# Does $A\vDash B$? where $B$ has free variables?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

> Let $B(\cdot), T(\cdot)$ and $M(\cdot , \cdot)$ be relational symbols in some first-order language. Let:
>
> $A(x,y) := (\forall x(B(x)\to T(x))) \land (\forall x \forall y(M(x,y)\to (T(x)\to T(y)))\land M(x,y)$
>
> $B(x,y) :=  \lnot T(y)\to \lnot B(x) $
>
> Does $A\vDash B$?

Where $\vDash$ is defined as $\vDash_{t}$, i.e. $\Gamma\vDash_{t} A$ iff any model **and** valuation $M,\nu$ that satisfy $\Gamma$ also satisfy $A$.

How should I approach this kind of question?

- I tried using deduction theorem to check if $A\to B$  is valid, but this got out of hand fairly quickly.
- If I were to try disproving this statement, I could have come up with an interpretation $M$ s.t. $M\vDash A$ but $M \not \vDash B$. But I can't think of (an intuitive) one.
- A naive attmept: Since $x,y$ occur as free variables in some of these expressions, it seems like I could "eliminate" the $\forall$ quantifiers (since they already allow any particular valuation $\nu$ of $x,y$). In this case, if the set $\Gamma = \lbrace B(x)\to T(x) , M(x,y)\to (T(x)\to T(y)), M(x,y), \lnot T(y) \rbrace$ is satisfied by $M,\nu$, then (again, after using deduction thm.) it also holds that $M,\nu\vDash \lnot B(x)$. But I don't know if (and how) I can justify eliminating the quantifiers in $A$. If anything, it goes against GEN inference rule in Hilbert's Calculus, and I should have introduced some Skolem constants or functions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I added missing details about $\vDash$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use a standard semantic argument for this.

Suppose that $M \models A$, and let $m_1, m_2 \in M$ be such that $M \models A(m_1,m_2)$. We want to show that $M\models B(m_1,m_2)$, i.e. $M\models ¬T(m_2)→¬B(m_1)$.

Indeed, suppose that $M \models ¬T(m_2)$. Since $M \models ∀x∀y(M(x,y)→(T(x)→T(y))$ and $M \models M(m_1,m_2)$ we obtain that $M \models T(m_1)→T(m_2)$. From our assumption this implies that $M \models \lnot T(m_1)$. Finally since $M \models ∀x(B(x)→T(x))$, we have that $M \models \lnot B(m_1)$ from the previous result. Putting all this together, we have that $M \models ¬T(m_2)→¬B(m_1)$, i.e. $M \models B(m_1,m_2)$ proving our claim.

Comment: This is exactly the sequence which led me through my naive attempt. You can formulate the assumption that $M \vDash \lnot T(m_{2}) $ by applying deduction theorem on $B(m_1, m_2)$  and assuming $\lbrace A(m_1,m_2), \lnot T(m_{2}) \rbrace$ is satisfied, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, although the deduction theorem is used more in the context of proofs, i.e. $\Sigma \cup \{A\} \vdash B \iff \Sigma \vdash A→B$. In this context, it suffices to show that if $M \models \lnot T(m_2)$, then $M \models ¬B(m_1) $. This is exactly the semantic definition of $M⊨¬T(m_2)→¬B(m_1)$.