# Prove or disprove: $\varphi \vDash^{t} \chi $

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

> Let
>
> $\varphi = H(x) \to A(x)$
>
> $\chi = \forall x(\exists y(R(x,y)\land H(y))\to \exists y(R(x,y)\land A(y)))$
>
> Does $\varphi \vDash^{t} \chi$?

Similar to a [previous question I posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4027946/does-a-vdash-b-where-b-has-free-variables), except now it seems less straightforward.

By the looks of it, it seems not true. This is my attempt:

- $\chi = \forall x(\exists y(R(x,y)\land H(y))\to \exists y(R(x,y)\land A(y))) \backsim \exists x\exists y(R(x,y)\land H(y))\to \exists z(R(x,z)\land A(z))) = \chi^\prime $
- We show that $\lbrace \varphi, \lnot\chi^\prime \rbrace $ is satisfiable by some $M,\nu$
- So if $M,\nu \vDash \exists x\exists y(R(x,y)\land H(y))$ then $M,\nu \not\vDash \exists z(R(x,z)\land A(z)) \iff M,\nu \vDash \forall z(\lnot R(x,z)\lor \lnot A(z))$
- For $D^M=\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$, $H^M=\lbrace 1 \rbrace ,A^M=\lbrace 0 \rbrace, R^M=\lbrace(0,1),(1,1) \rbrace, \nu(x)=0$, indeed $\lbrace \varphi, \lnot\chi^\prime \rbrace $ is satisfiable by $M,\nu$. Thus, $\varphi \not\vDash^{t} \chi$.

Is this a valid solution? I think the question was not intended to be answered with a made-up counterexample of $M$ and $\nu$ (and the one I gave is quite peculiar), but I didn't find any other way.